# Route traffic selectively through OpenVPN as a SOCKS proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, openvpn, socks-proxy

Is it possible to convert OpenVPN traffic into a SOCKS proxy locally, so that applications can use the VPN only when needed by connecting to the SOCKS proxy?

I'm aiming for something like [Underleech Seedboxes](http://www.underleech.org/whmcs/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=18), but I don't have their opvn file, so I'm attempting to replicate this. This question [Is it possible to route only a specific application through a VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/251051/is-it-possible-to-route-only-a-specific-application-through-a-vpn) is what I'm aiming to do, but I'm running on a Windows machine, and the answer did not provide a concrete solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have made your question unnecessarily complicated.  A proxy and a VPN do two different tasks.  If what you want to do is send traffic from specific applications through a VPN, that is one question.  If you want to send traffic from specific apps through a proxy, that is a second question.  You do not configure a VPN on one side and use proxy settings on the other side to connect.  Nor can you use a VPN connection to connect to a proxy.  Can not work, period.  You can VPN to a server that also has a proxy set up, and then use that servers proxy if both services are available.

Comment: Like this? https://superuser.com/a/644130